# Элемент List при передаче в другую форму оказывается пустым

Tags: c#, list

На первой форме Form1 создаётся публичный элемент List list1. Во второй форме, при обращении к этому элементу, он оказывается пустым.

```
Form1:
public List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
list1.Add(""); // при отладке, при наведении на list1, показано, что count после этого равен 1.
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();

Form2:
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
if (frm.list1[0] == "") {...} // здесь count уже равен 0 и всплывает исключение: Ссылка за пределами диапазона.
```

Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Потому что списки разные. list1 формы 1 и list1 формы 2 это 2 разных объекта.

Comment: @SultanovShamil тогда можете подсказать, как его правильно передать?

Comment: Заводите отдельный класс, который будет содержать все ваши бизнес-данные (список), создавайте экземпляр в корне агрегации (program.cs) и передавайте в формы параметром (конструктора). Таким образом обе формы ваши будут работать с одним экземпляром класса и одним экземпляром списка в него помещенного.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас есть 2 формы: `Form1` и `Form2`.

При запуске программы создается экземпляр класса `Form1` (назовем его `frm1`). Вы с ним работаете на протяжении какого-то времени, потом создаете экземпляр класса `Form2` (назовем его `frm2`) и отображаете его. На этом этапе `frm2` ничего не знает о `frm1`. Поэтому если вам нужно работать со списком из `frm1` внутри `frm2`, лучше этот список передать в качестве параметра в конструктор класса `Form2`, либо присвоить заранее определенному свойству Form2 после вызова конструктора и перед вызовом метода `Show()`.

Вариант с конструктором:

```
class Form1
{
    public List<string> list1 = new List<string>();

    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(list1);
        frm2.Show();
    }
}

class Form2
{
    public List<string> list1Copy;

    public Form2(List<string> list1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list1Copy = list1;
    }
}
```

Вариант со свойством:

```
class Form1
{
    public List<string> list1 = new List<string>();

    public void ShowForm2()
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.list1Copy = list1;
        frm2.Show();
    }
}

class Form2
{
    public List<string> list1Copy;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Теперь вы можете работать со списком по ссылке `list1Copy`. Эти подходы наиболее простые, но не являются наилучшими с точки зрения архитектуры приложения.

У вас же в коде в `Form2` создается новый, совершенно другой экземпляр `Form1` (т.е. это уже будет `frm1_1 != frm1`). В нем не будут видны те изменения, которые вы проводили с первым экземпляром `frm1`. Поэтому ваш подход неверный.